# pandas equivalent for grep

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grep

I'm new comer for pandas,
For dataframe like:

```
N  Chem    Val
A  Sodium  9
B  Sodium  10
A  Chlorid 7
B  Chlorid 10
A  Sodium  17
```

I'd like to do like `grep`in bash, to select lines containing `'A'` in 1st column and `'Sodium'` in 3rd column :

```
A  Sodium  9
A  Sodium  17
```

How should I do? I guess I need to use `df[].str.contains()`?
Thx

Comment: Is your example 3 columns or 1?  Could you show your column headers as well?

Comment: sorry it's actually 3 columns

Comment: It looks like the first row of your dataframe is supposed to be your column headers.

Comment: Yes, sorry , first row is the column headers.

Comment: Very similar: [Pandas: grep like function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12625650/395857)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `.str.contains()` on a column of the data frame to return a boolean `Series`.  You can also perform logical `and` and `or` operations on multiple Series.  Finally, passing a logical Series as a key to a data frame will return only the values that are true.

```
bool1 = df.N.str.contains('A')          # True for rows of N == 'A'
bool2 = df.Chem.str.contains('Sodium')  # True for rows of Chem == 'Sodium'
df[bool1 & bool2]   # selects rows where N=='A' AND Chem=='Sodium'

returns (without including the index):
N  Chem    Val
A  Sodium  9
A  Sodium  17
```

Comment: I tried this, df[bool], but it turns out:  Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Index: [] I don't know what's going wrong

Comment: No, I'm not trying df['bool']. See my new edits for the question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it actually works. I made stupid mistakes! many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, using `query` is the most natural way to express this type of command

```
df.query('N == "A" & Chem == "Sodium"')

   N    Chem  Val
0  A  Sodium    9
4  A  Sodium   17
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have meant just selecting keys based on both columns, it's better not to use contains. It is for the case when you have to select sodium_A, sodium_B, etc. out of other strings(which means it could be slower than basic multiple selection).

```
import pandas as pd

# Your sample data
df = pd.read_table('sample.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)

print(df[(df.loc[:, 0] == 'A') & (df.loc[:, 1] == 'Sodium')])

   0       1   2
1  A  Sodium   9
5  A  Sodium  17
```